# Can I use "aws-toolkit for VSCode" to keep my credentials safely there while I am doing app development?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, credentials, aws-toolkit, .env

I am working on a Flutter + Typescript-NodeJS application and I need to use Amazon S3 directly from inside my Flutter and also NodeJS code. What I am doing now is keeping my access and secret keys within a `.env` file inside my project but I think this is not the safest way to do it. So I researched and found out there is an extension for VSCode named `AWS-Toolkit` that gives you the access to work with your AWS server from inside the VSCode, but I couldn't find an example to see how can I use it for my specific "keeping my credentials safe" issue?

For example, how should I replace such a code that uses `.env` file:

```
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Toolkit for VSCode extension [reads your AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/aws-credentials.html) from the same shared config and credentials files used by the AWS CLI.

The toolkit's [debugging support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/serverless-apps.html) for SAM applications allows access to the shared AWS credential profiles when debugging a Lambda function.  The `aws` key in the `launch.json` [debug configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/serverless-apps-run-debug-config-ref.html) lets you configure which shared profile to use:

```json
// launch.json
{
  "type": "aws-sam",
  "request": "direct-invoke",
  "name": "debug my great function",
  "invokeTarget": {
    "target": "code",
    "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/lambda",
    "lambdaHandler": "func.handler"
  },
  "lambda": {
    "runtime": "nodejs18.x",
    "payload": { "json": { "foo": "bar" } },
    "environmentVariables": { "FOO_ENV": "bar-env" }
  },
  "aws": {
    "credentials": "profile:my-profile",
    "region": "us-east-1"
  },
},
```

As far as the client side goes, you should of course not expose AWS credentials to your app at all.

Comment: Also, if the `aws` key is not in `launch.json`, AWS Toolkit will pass your current Toolkit credentials to the Docker container invoked by `sam`.